# Which devil fruit is this, and what happend to it?

Tags: one-piece

During the punk hazard arc we can see one of the apples in the sleigh transform into a devil fruit just before smiley turns every thing in to a deadly gaseous goo. [image]

What happened to this devil fruit afterwards, and which devil fruit is it to begin with. Is it ever shown?

Comment: Since the marines go back to get their crew mates, i assume they would have acquired the fruit too! Nothing is shown as of now :)

Comment: I guess [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2979/6166) is related to your first question. When Smiley died and the Devil was released, he reincarnated into the apple. Aside from that, anybody's guess is as good as yours as to what happened to it. Caesar intended to recreate Smiley with it, but he never got the chance to go and get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only answer this question partially because of the information we currently have on One Piece.

The name of the Devil Fruit is: [Sara Sara no Mi, Model: Axolotl](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sara_Sara_no_Mi,_Model:_Axolotl).
If you wanna look up the name, it can be found in chapter 673, page 12.

As for what happened to the Devil Fruit, I have no clue since neither the manga nor the anime have shown/hinted at it being transported afterwards. So it might as well still be on Punk Hazard.

Answer (score 1):

Because Smiley died the fruit was re-circulated,

you know how vegapunk was able to give inanimate objects the powers of a devil fruit, Caesar Clown did the same for smiley

Comment: This happend just before Smiley turned everything into a deadly gaseous goo. Aka just before he died. Do you maybe have some source material to back this statement up?