# How long does Devil Fruit take to re-spawn after the death of user?

Tags: one-piece

After the death of Devil Fruit (DF) user, the DF re-spawns. This has been [explained](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2985/6345). After the death of Ace, **Mera Mera no Mi** re-spawned as shown in chapter 701.

Marshall D. Teach, user of the **Yami Yami no Mi** fruit, stole the power of the **Gura Gura no Mi** from White Beard after he died. It is explained that it does not re-spawn as soon as the user dies.

So how much time does it take to re-spawn and how long does the power of DF remain inside the user after he/she dies?

Answer (score 2):

The only proof we have seen so far, indicates that the ability re-spawns immediately, as can be seen when [Smiley](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Smiley) died during the Punk Hazard arc.

[image]

Marshall D. Teach isn't a good counter-example as he probably didn't use the conventional way to obtain his second devil fruit power. He must have used his powers to obtain the power instead of just eating it. I believe that he used his powers to trap the spirit before it could be reborn. I believe he absorbed the devil, the moment it got out of Whitebeard's body and before it could travel to the nearest fruit in order to be reborn.

The fact that Caeser deliberately put a sack of apples near the location he would kill Salamander indicates that he was aware of the fact that it would re-spawn immediately. If it wouldn't, there wouldn't be any point in putting a bunch of apples in the sleigh near Smiley. And even if it was just a major coincidence that the apples were there, it still shows that the Salamander fruit demon was reborn the instant Smiley died.

I don't think it is a well known fact though. Otherwise the Marines would have put a fruit similar to the fire fruit nearby Marineford to keep that awesome power within the Marines. Or maybe they did and Doflamingo stole the fruit in the end. We can only speculate on how Doflamingo got the Fire fruit, as it hasn't been revealed and I doubt it will be revealed further down the series.

Comment: "He absorbed the devil, the moment it got out of Whitebeard's body and before it could travel to the nearest fruit in order to be reborn." when is this mention?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino It wasn't, that's how I assume it went down. The spirit needed to leave the body before it could travel to the nearest fruit and with Blackbeard's ability I assumed he sucked the spirit in before it could get too far. Nothing really has been said or seen about the reincarnation of fruits, except for the Salamander fruit.

Comment: I suggest you to add that on your answer, for now it looks like it's really happen. Even if it is, there's no canon proof for now.

Comment: @PeterRaeves [When a Devil Fruit user dies, their ability is reborn into another fruit of the same kind.](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Growth) This suggest not immediately but availability of fruit of same kind.

Comment: @mirroroftruth Grammatically it says "When" = "At that time" and the second part of the sentence is in the present tense. So that sentence says "At the time a user dies, the ability is reborn", not later nor at any other time. If it could also be any other time it would say "the fruit will be reborn" in the future tense. Proof can be seen with the Salamander fruit, which indeed is reborn at the exact same moment. The earthquake fruit was transferred at the time of death. There hasn't been any counter-example so far in the manga that would proof the statement wrong.

Comment: "At the time a user dies, the ability is reborn" then Gura Gura no Mi should have reborn as soon as White Beard died and Black beard should not have it. Because there was certain time lapse, at least more time than reborn of smiley's ability after death of smiley.

Comment: Nice point with Ace and the marine but did the marines know what "same kind" was needed to incarnate the fire fruit?