# When do "immortal" Devil Fruits respawn?

Tags: one-piece

There is a question regarding [the respawn time of regular Devil Fruits (DF)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13660/how-long-does-devil-fruit-take-to-re-spawn-after-the-death-of-user?rq=1), but I am interested in the possibility of creating an immortal army using the same one-time DF, namely the *Ope Ope no Mi* and the *Yomi Yomi no Mi*.

The *Ope Ope no Mi* can perform the "Perennial Youth Operation" which kills the DF user and gives eternal youth (and so potentially eternal life) to the subject. The *Yomi Yomi no Mi* enables the soul of the user to return to his body **after his death**.

Does the *Ope Ope no Mi* respawn after the Perennial Youth Operation (the user's death) or after the death of the operated person? Does the *Yomi Yomi no Mi* respawn after the "First" death or after the soul leaves this world forever?

At least for the *Ope Ope no Mi* there is no body left to contain the fruit's powers and after Doflamingo wanted to become immortal by Rosinante eating the fruit and performing the operation, the powers can not be stored in the operated person's body.

Could one create an army of immortals using one of this DFs?

Comment: As your question is interesting but a bit too wide, i suggest removing the 3rd paragraph and asking it in another question

Answer (score 1):

No, these fruits cannot create an immortal army, they are not designed with that in mind. Even after giving someone eternal youth, that is all he will get, he will just remain "young" forever. Anyone will still be able to kill the user in a fight, he may die to an accident etc. The same applies Yomi Yomi no Mi, you get another life but you are not immortal. Also, even if someone has the Yomi Yomi no mi, and his head gets cut there is no body to return, because he will die again immeditally.

Ope Ope no Mi respawns after the users death (the one who eat the fruit) because the person who gained eternal life has no "connection" with the fruit itself.

Comment: Of course someone with eternal youth can be killed somehow but (s)he won't die from age, does (s)he? So one could find out what kind of fruit is needed for the Ope Ope no Mi to respawn and loop the eating and usage of the fruit to create a dozen of semi immortals. The younds like something Teach would do, or the dragons.

Comment: Since Ope Ope mi is able to "heal" people, when someone preforms the youth operation he basically "fixes" the cells of that person. Aging is ofter described as result of cell damage which accumulates over time (this is a bit offtopic and for start you can read more about it on wikipedia), so my interpretation of opes ability is that it removes the defects of dna alteration. The theme of the fruit is based around healing so this is kind of a plausible explanation, as far as "real life process" can be applied in one piece

Comment: I agree and this is in way a new point of view for me. The operation prevents a person from aging and if the fruit reincarnates as the original user dies, there can be more than one person effected by this effect at the same time. That was the background of my question.

Comment: yeah that is possible, x number of people could already have been give the procedure

Comment: "his head gets cut there is no body to return" - Brook vs [Zeo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zeo) shows otherwise.

Comment: that is after his fruit was activated

Comment: yes so when the user gets executed, The fruit gets active, the soul returns to the body and so does the head.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you got it wrong. The Ope Ope no Mi only gives eternal youth, and the Yomi Yomi no Mi gives 1 extra shot at life and it's not as overpowered as it sounds.

If you were to perform the eternal surgery on someone like Makino, she would just live forever and wouldn't become stronger or invincible. She would just get the ability to never die from old age.

It's the same with the Yomi Yomi fruit, which only gives you an extra life. For instance, if you drown because you ate the Yomi Yomi no Mi, a devil fruit, when your soul comes back you will just drown again and then be dead for good. It doesn't give you any extra power.

Comment: But if you were a dragon you would buy the Ope Ope no Mi and a slave to stop your aging and others would do so too and get never agind soldiers if the fruit respawns. So in fact if the fruit respawns after the operation, there could be a group of persons that never grow old and can train or wait for a strong DF forever. Imagine a never aging doctor who studies since 300 years or a never aging Zorro who trains for the same time.